# convert an int array to another fixed length array with lambda

Tags: java, arrays, lambda

What is equivalent of following function with lambda?

```
private String convertWeekDayToBitString(int[] ia) {
    int[] sa = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    for (int i : ia) {
        if (i > 0 && i < 8) {
          sa[i-1] = 1;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.toString(sa).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").trim();
}
```

The purpose of this function, is to mark "day of week" to 1 according to input array. For example, if input array is [5,6], output should be 0,0,0,0,1,1,0

Comment: That method will throw `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0` for `replaceAll("[", "")`. Are you sure you want to get lambda version which also throws such exception? If not than please clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This shouldn't be done with a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You could stream 7 values using an `IntStream`, and for each one check if it's in the input array. If the input array is guaranteed to be sorted, you could use a single statement for this:

```
return IntStream
    .range(0, 7)
    .mapToObj(x -> String.valueOf(Arrays.binarySearch(ia, x) >= 0 ? 1 : 0))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```